# How can I remove a persistent attempt by macOS to auto-mount network volume after it was removed from the Users & Groups login items

Tags: mount, nas, login-items

I have a 2019 MacBook Pro running macOS Monterey 12.3.1

I used to have an item for my user in System Preferences>Users & Groups>Login Items that would auto-mount my NAS volume using my previous username and password whenever I would start the system.

I recently changed the NAS volume's username and password and also deleted the NAS volume from the Login Items list.

Despite all that, the Finder persists in attempting to auto-mount the NAS volume using the old username.

I just spent 2 hours with a senior Apple tech with no resolution in sight.

Attempted troubleshooting tasks:

1. restarted system - problem exists
2. restarted system in Safe Mode — problem gone
3. examined keychain for entry linked to NAS volume and old username — none exists
4. examined startup items folder — empty
5. cleared all cache files — problem remains
6. used Cocktail to search for corrupted preferences files — 2 unrelated files found
7. examined Users//Library/Preferences folder for any files with the words "start", "log", or "user" — none found

Anyone have any ideas on what to do next?

TIA!

[image: dialog which cannot be eliminated]

[image: my login Items list]